# What is the structure of the Android PackageManagerService?

Tags: android

I would like to know , what are the sequence of steps that happen once
the user clicks on the "installApp"??

I need to disable the installation of apps(when user tries to install
the app by clicking on install), based on certain conditions, how can
i do it??
Any suggestions will help.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have no control over the installation process. If there is an APK, the user can install it, and your code will not be executed until the installation is complete.

Comment: After the user clicks "The downloaded .apk", i guess the PackageManager comes into picture and it in tern uses PackageManagerService which has a methos to install.I was thinking if i comment that install method in the PackageManagerService, can we achive that? atleast temporarily.

Comment: @Geetag only if you are building your own rom